# Python: ways to synchronize trio tasks and regular threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-trio

I find myself in the situation that I need to synchronize Trio tasks with Python threads. At the moment, I am using `threading.Lock` objects that Trio tasks have to acquire with `trio.run_sync_in_worker_thread(lock.acquire)`.

I think it should also be possible to use `trio. Lock` locks and have the threads acquire them with `trio.BlockingTrioPortal.run_sync(lock.acquire)`.

Does either of these solutions have advantages over the other?

Would in in principle be possible to do better than this? E.g. to implement a "native" trio method that waits for a `threading.Lock` without the need for a separate worker thread, or are there fundamental reasons why this is required?

Comment: You mean `trio.BlockingTrioPortal.run(lock.acquire)` since `trio.Lock.acquire` is an async method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are fine. I'd recommend to use the method which causes less work, i.e. if the external thread acquires the lock ten times per Trio task's once, then use a thread lock, and vice versa.

A `threading.Lock` always blocks the thread trying to acquire it, so taking it from Trio either requires a separate thread (which your first method already does anyway), or the lock's holder needs to signal the Trio task that it has released the lock (which your second method does anyway), so there is no clear advantage for implementing a lower-level solution.

Answer (score 1):

Matthias's answer is excellent. To add: there is one theoretical advantage to using a `trio.Lock`, which is that then at least the Trio-side calls will support cancellation. However, there is currently also a major practical obstacle, which is that currently, using `BlockingTrioPortal` to call `lock.acquire` and `lock.release` doesn't work :-(. See [this issue I just filed](https://github.com/python-trio/trio/issues/680) for details. So until that's fixed, you'll have to use `threading.Lock` and `run_sync_in_worker_thread`. After it's fixed, though, I would default to using `trio.Lock` for the cancellation thing.

EDIT: on further thought, I remembered that trio does already have a version of `Lock` that works with `BlockingTrioPortal`, it's just obscure: `trio.Semaphore(1, max_value=1)`. We should still fix the general case, but in the mean time this might be a useful thing to know about.